# Eclipse warnings: fmt:formatDate and html:hidden must be empty

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jstl, struts-1

I am doing some manipulations with date. It works fine. But eclipse shows warnings such as `<fmt:formatDate> and <html:hidden> must be empty`.
I tried rewriting this constructions but nothing changes. I use these libraries.

The following is my code:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<c:set var="date_str">    
    <fmt:formatDate value="${myForm.itemShop.date}">
        <jsp:attribute name="pattern">
            <bean:message key="date.pattern" />
        </jsp:attribute>
    </fmt:formatDate>
</c:set>

<html:hidden property="datePattern">
    <jsp:attribute name="value">
        <bean:message key="date.pattern" />
    </jsp:attribute>
</html:hidden>
```

Comment: Write your full tag library code also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warnings are due to the `TLD` which specifies `<body-content>empty<body-content>` for the tag `formatDate`.

This means that the `body-content` should be empty for the `formatDate` tag. Here is the [documentation link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/index.html) for this tag.

I think you can safely ignore these warnings.